# Executing thousands of SQLServer queries at one time

Tags: sql-server

I have a SQL Server database in which I store millions of records. Now, I have to delete a big number of records continuously, so what I do is running thousands of queries like this within the same execution:

```
delete TWEET 
from TWEET 
where REQUEST_ID >= x and TWEET_ID = y and ID < z
```

The single query is immediate, but putting them all together is extremely slow.

What would you suggest to me?

Comment: Can you come up with a single query that handles those cases more broadly?

Comment: either `and id in ([your ids separated by comma])` or put all your ids in a table, and `delete from join table on id`

Comment: How's your transaction log looking?

Comment: @tadman unfortunately it would slow down even more, because it will scan a lot of records not to be deleted

Comment: If you can't index these effectively, then yeah, it will be slow, but I have a feeling this is a schema design problem more than a run millions of queries one.

Comment: @tadman so how should I redesign my schema according to the attributes that you see in the Where clause?

Comment: I think you need to figure out why these would be deleted in the first place, and then figure out if you can express that as a singular field, or two fields at most, which can be indexed.

Comment: What are the current indexes on the table again plz?

Comment: as @tadman said, the main question is why are you deleting those rows. Are they Tweets for specific dates? or specific status?

Comment: because I'm putting tweets and retweets in my db, the retweets are almost a full duplicate, it just differs for one column, so I have to delete them while another process saves the records

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this. You can delete 100000 rows every turn. This works faster than delete all rows in the same time.

```
DECLARE @RC INT = 1

WHILE @RC > 0
BEGIN

delete TOP(100000) 
from TWEET 
where REQUEST_ID >= x and TWEET_ID = y and ID < z

SET @RC = @@ROWCOUNT

END
```

Comment: Should I run this multiple times or does it work with a one time run?

Comment: Execute only one time. We have a while loop and it iterate deletion until finish the records.

Comment: I have to run this from Java so the y and z will be different for each round of the while loop that I use in Java. Is it going to be stuck in the loop with your solution, or does it work with multiple different parameters?

Comment: y and z should not be changed until it deletes all rows. If it is not stable, it will cause uncertainty and it would break the loop before deleting all rows, or get in infinite loops.

Comment: Ok, but that’s the problem: in the meantime the query deletes the duplicates, another process adds other ones, so it won’t probably get out of the loop. How can I solve that? It should be a real time cleaning while the tweets are saved into the db.

Comment: You should add a time or max id filter too. it prevents looking newly inserted rows.

Answer (score 0):

Using a JOINed table is probably your best bet (see below). Another option is to use Service Broker: you send a delete request into SB and some asynchronous process deletes it when is has the CPU to do so.

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------
--  Create a table to hold the delete requests:
CREATE TABLE DeleteTweets (
    ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY
    , REQUEST_ID INT
    , TWEET_ID INT
    )
GO

------------------------------------------------------------------------
--  Create an index to keep the deletions fast:
CREATE INDEX IX_DeleteTweets ON dbo.DeleteTweets (REQUEST_ID, TWEET_ID)
GO

------------------------------------------------------------------------
--  However you can put your delete requests into that table. This might
--  be part of you front-end application or via some batch process:
INSERT INTO dbo.DeleteTweets
        ( REQUEST_ID, TWEET_ID )
VALUES  ( 0, /*REQUEST_ID*/, 0 /*TWEET_ID*/)
    , ( 0, /*REQUEST_ID*/, 0 /*TWEET_ID*/)
    , ( 0, /*REQUEST_ID*/, 0 /*TWEET_ID*/)
    , ( 0, /*REQUEST_ID*/, 0 /*TWEET_ID*/)
    , ( 0, /*REQUEST_ID*/, 0 /*TWEET_ID*/)
GO

------------------------------------------------------------------------
--  Delete from the main table via JOIN:
DELETE t
FROM TWEET t
    INNER JOIN dbo.DeleteTweets dt
        ON t.REQUEST_ID = dt.REQUEST_ID
        AND t.TWEET_ID = dt.TWEET_ID
GO

------------------------------------------------------------------------
--  Once they're done, empty the table so you can re-fill with new deletion requests:
TRUNCATE TABLE dbo.DeleteTweets
GO
```

Comment: It's not clear to me why delete using join between TWEET and DeletedTweets makes any difference, would you please clarify that. BTW, creating/updating index is also time consuming. Also, inserting rows into DeleteTweets takes time.

Comment: I already tried an INNER JOIN but it worked even worse than my query.
@FLICKER I added a comment below the question where I explain the reasons

Answer (score 0):

--IN QUERY WINDOW 1

```
    DROP TABLE TWEETDEL
    GO
    DROP TABLE TWEET
    GO

    CREATE TABLE TWEET
        (ID int NOT NULL
        ,REQUEST_ID AS ID*2
        ,TWEET_ID AS ID*10  
        )   
    GO

    INSERT TWEET WITH (TABLOCKX) (ID )
    SELECT TOP 20000000 id
    FROM
          (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY a.id) AS id
            FROM sys.sysobjects AS a, sys.syscolumns AS b, sys.syscolumns AS c) x
    GO  

    ALTER TABLE TWEET ADD PRIMARY KEY (ID)
    GO
    SELECT IDENTITY(INT,1,1) AS TWEETDELPK, *
    INTO TWEETDEL
    FROM TWEET
    WHERE REQUEST_ID%14=0
    GO
    ALTER TABLE TWEETDEL ADD PRIMARY KEY (TWEETDELPK)
    GO
    ALTER TABLE TWEETDEL
       ADD CONSTRAINT fk101
       FOREIGN KEY (ID) REFERENCES TWEET(ID) ON DELETE CASCADE
    GO
```

-- IN THE SAME WINDOW

```
    SET NOCOUNT OFF
    DECLARE @ID INT

    CR:

    DELETE TOP (SELECT CNT FROM ##) t WITH (PAGLOCK)
    FROM TWEET AS t
    WHERE EXISTS
        (SELECT 1 FROM TWEET AS x WHERE T.ID = X.ID)

    IF @@ROWCOUNT >0 GOTO CR
```

-- IN ANOTHER WINDOW

```
    CREATE TABLE ## (CNT INT)

    INSERT ## SELECT 1000


    select COUNT(1) from tweetdel
    select COUNT(1) from tweet
```

CHECK FOR LOCKING - IF LOCKS ARE STAYING OPEN TOO LONG, RAISE OR LOWER CHUNKSIZE ACCORDINGLY

```
    UPDATE ## SET CNT =5000

    SELECT resource_type, resource_associated_entity_id,  
        request_status, request_mode,request_session_id,  
        resource_description   
    FROM sys.dm_tran_locks  
    WHERE resource_database_id = DB_ID()
    AND request_mode in ('x')
```